# using enums within a class that also contains a class that has enums.......I know but check it out

Tags: android, enums, gson, inner-classes

So at first I thought this was a dumb question but as I considered this class' implementation I realized I was maybe approaching this wrong or it's more complicated than I thought. I also don't know if I fully understand the proper usage of enums. 
Here is what I want to do:

I have a class of Competitors. A competitor has an Age category which can only be 1 of 4 possible values so I put this into an embedded enum class. Here is where it gets tricky:

Each Competitor has 7 categories/divisions where they are ranked by a limited set of values for class. For example, they may be ranked "Class B" for the revolver Division.

I want to be able to create one Competitor that has all the values I'm assigning to the Competitor fields plus a list (I'm currently using a separate object "Division") of all the Competitor's rankings for each Division. I want to eventually be able to parse the complete Competitor object (Divisions and all) into a Json using the Gson library but I can't wrap my head around whether I'm approaching this right or if the parsing methods will even be able to parse it correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
public class Competitors {

    private String referenceNum;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String memberNum;
    private boolean lady;
    private enum Age{
        JUNIOR,
        ADULT,
        SENIOR,
        SUPER_SENIOR;
    }
    private Division divisionRankings;

}

 class Division{
     private String revolver;
     private String singleStack;
     private String production;
     private String limited;
     private String limited10;
     private String open;
     private String pistolCaliberCarbine;

     private enum Classes{
         U, D, C, B, A, M, GM;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible model that maps well to JSON:

```
public class Competitor {

    public enum Age {
        JUNIOR,
        ADULT,
        SENIOR,
        SUPER_SENIOR;
    }

    public String referenceNum;
    public String firstName;
    public String lastName;
    public String memberNum;
    public boolean lady;
    public Age age;

    public Map<String, Ranking> divisionRankings;
}

public enum Ranking {
    U, D, C, B, A, M, GM;
}
```

You need to make fields public if you want to make them accessible to the outside world (or use getters and setters).

The `Map<String, ?>` will translate to a JSON object; in your case the string keys would be the division names.

Comment: I am going to use getters and setters. How would I initialize the 'division' keys when creating an object? Could create the divisionRankings Map in the Competitors constructor and set all the default values to "U" for (unclassified)?

Comment: For example yes. Or you can create and assign an empty LinkedHashMap in the empty constructor and add values later.

Comment: Check out my new implementation of this class. Am I on the right track. Enums throw me off

Comment: The new code looks fine but you should rather declare the Ranking enum public because it's supposed to be accessible from outside the class. Enums are just final classes with a finite set of instances, there's nothing fancy about that.